# autoloading multiple files on multiple folder with php?

Tags: php, autoload

**how to Autoload multiple files that may stored inside more than one folder ? 
what i already do is like demonstrated at the pic : 
[image]**

creating a file required at Index.php [ init.php ] which contains :

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(function ($class){
    require_once "classes/class.$class.php";
});
```

**question no 1** : how to autoload another file which lives in another folder eg : **Conf/class.Conf.php** ?
**question no 2** : can i use another name convention for the other auto-loading process ?

it'll be better if you provide a coded example :)

Comment: Use PSR-4 autoloader (it comes with composer)

Comment: @tereško can you give an example ??

Comment: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/examples/

Comment: You can register another autoload function using `spl_autoload_register`

Comment: You right, thats actually not going to work. It should check if file exists. Maybe check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34920621/4471134

Comment: @DanMiller you're right thanks for shedding light on the key Answer , the problem solved after modifying the code at : Init.php :) :)

Answer (score 2):

the Problem Solved as @dan-miller Comment mention checking for file existence then require it for each new folder

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(function ($class){
    $filename="classes/$class.php";
        if(!file_exists($filename))
        {
            return "file : $filename is not Exist on the Given Path";
        }
    require_once "classes/$class.php";
});
spl_autoload_register(function ($class){
    $filename="conf/$class.php";
        if(!file_exists($filename))
        {
            return "file : $filename is not Exist on the Given Path";
        }
    require_once "conf/$class.php";
});
```

*** that's for testing Purpose