# How to use spl_autoload_register for multiple directories in PHP

Tags: php, frameworks, helper, spl-autoload-register

Follow the code for the autoload class in multiple paths.

This question is to remedy php users for correct usage of spl in various directories
After a long time I elaborated this to sanitize my code.

```
    spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    $paths = array(
        'classes/',
        'engine/'
    );

    foreach($paths as $path){

        $file = LIBRARY . $path . str_replace('\\', '/', strtolower($class)) . '.php';

        if(file_exists($file)){
            $files = array($file);
        }
    }

    foreach($files as $file){
        if(is_file($file)){
            include_once($file);
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    
});
```

Comment: You want to share a solution here instead of asking a question, right?! You can do this, but you should do it in the Q/A format. First edit the question part to ask an actual question. Explain the problem with enough details, so that also other people would be able to understand and answer it, then add your answer as a separate answer in the "You Answer" field below. See [can I answer my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Wow thanks I recently started on the platform ^^
I'm sorry for begin late!